# Jquery chart/diagram/drawing plugins or methods to create wheel of life diagram

Tags: jquery, html, css, charts, diagram

[image: I need to create the following chart in jquery]

I want to create the above chart in jquery,html and css. I want to know of there is any existing jquery library or function to do it easily. If I want to make one of my own probably which will be the best jquery drawing library to take the chart ?

Comment: I don't think there's any charting APIs that will do that for you, `Highcharts` would be the most likely to though. To do it yourself you'd be best using `Raphael`.

Comment: I might have to give it a try, thanks for the suggestion.

Wow now that's easy .. I just checked the library !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into the wonderful d3.js library http://d3js.org/

EDIT: I remembered the name of the chart type. Polar.

Here is a great walk through with d3.js

http://kreese.net/blog/2012/08/26/d3-js-creating-a-polar-area-diagram-radial-bar-chart/